# $y_n (x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\cdots+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$,$y(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n x$, so continuity of $y_n(x)$ & y(x)

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Let $$y_n (x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\cdots+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$$ and  $$y(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty}y_n(x). $$ Discuss the continuity of $y_n (x)$ $(n \in\mathbb N)$ and $y(x)$ at $x=0.$

$$-$$
$$-$$
**My attempt**:
i have have first used the formula of sum of gp in this equation

$$y_n (x)=x^2+\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}+\cdots+\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$$

RHS can be written as

$$y_n(x)=x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}\right)$$

applying sum of GP $=a(1-r^n)/(1-r)$

$$y_n(x)=x^2\left[1\frac{(1-(\frac{1}{1+x^2})^n}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}\right]$$

that is

$$y_n(x)=x^2 \frac{\frac{(1+x^2)^n-1}{(1+x^2)^n}}{\frac{1+x^2-1}{1+x^2}}$$

which can also be written as

$$y_n(x)=\frac{(1+x^2)^{n}-1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$$

which gives me

$$y_n(x)=(1+x^2)-\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$$

so,if $$y(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty}y_n(x) $$

Hence

$$y(x)=1+x^2$$

So the function
$y_n(x)$ and $y(x)$

should be continuous at $0$ (by theorems of continuity and graph).

$$.$$

But according to **answer key**  $y_n(x)$ is continuous at $0$ but y(x) is not continuous at $0$

Can you please tell me why?

Comment: Could you check your formula after "which gives me" in the question for a few small values of $n$? I don't immediately see how geometric series gives that answer. By check I mean include the calculation steps in the question body, not in a comment.

Comment: @coffeemath ,did it

Comment: I think the algebra is off when you simplify the thing right after "applying GP" to get to the thing right after "which gives me".  When we divide $(1-A^n)$ by $(1-A)$ the result has a lot of terms, namely descending powers of $A$ starting with $A^{n-1}$. It doesn't become only a term or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}} = 0 $$
only if $1+x^2>1$, that is, if $x\neq 0$. For $x=0$ you have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1 $$
so
$$y(x) = 1 +x^2 \quad \text{for }x\neq 0$$
$$y(0) = 0. $$

Comment: so for $y_n(x)$ if n is a very huge number, and $x=0$ then $y_n(x)$ should also be discontinuous ,as for $x=0$ $y_n(x)=0$ but for $x\neq0$  $y_n(x) \text{is} 1+x^2$,is that correct.

Comment: No, all $y_n(x)$ are continuous, only their limit $y(x)$ is discontinuous. Think about the function $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$: it's a bell curve, of height $1$ (independently of $n$), but narrower and narrower for increasing $n$, so in the limit it tends to $0$ almost everywhere, except in its peak. Functions $y_n(x)$ for large $n$ are close to $1+x^2$, but near $x=0$ they have a sudden deviation and insteat going to $1$ they go to $0$. This deviation is significant only close to $0$, but it is continuous.

Comment: can you please tell me if these type of question repeat, how can I figure out the discontinuity on the limits function. Should I check the function at $0$ every time or at the point mentioned in the question.

Comment: You were doing well, you were just careless in asssuming that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}} = 0$. If you were more careful, you'd notice that $x=0$ is a special case, and that should make you check whether the limit is continuous there. In other similar questions, you should ask yourself a question, whether your reasoning works for all $x$, or are there some points where it doesn't work.

Comment: ,Thanks Sir I would be careful regarding that in future.